# gulp-rev-all fazendo replace no id dom-module

Tags: gulp, polymer

Estou tentando fazer o versionamento dos assets do meu polymer web app usando o gulp-rev-all. Porém, o gulp-rev-all está fazendo replace e adicionando hash também no id do dom-module.

Ex: `<dom-module id="cr-header.fd743a17">`

```
gulp.task('version-assets', ['vulcanize'], function () {
    if (production) {

        gulp
            .src(
            [
                folder.build + 'app/src/**/**/*.html',
                folder.build + 'app/src/**/*.js',
                folder.build + 'app/src/**/*.css',
                folder.build + 'app/index.html',
                folder.build + 'app/error-404.html',
            ])
            .pipe(RevAll.revision({ dontRenameFile: [/^\/favicon.ico$/g, /^\/index.html/g, /^\/error-404.html/g] }))
            .pipe(revdel())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build + 'app/'))
            .pipe(RevAll.manifestFile())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build + 'app/src'));
    }
});
```

Encontrei uma possível solução de como deve ser corrigido isso, porém, sinceramente não consegui entender como corrigir o meu caso. (pode ser visto aqui https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all/issues/97)

Answer (score 1):

Eu vi uma solução com replace também e eu achei ruim exatamente por causa desses conflitos que pode dar. Eu resolvi isso utilizando o **gulp-hash** de maneira que ele coloca o **hash** no nome do arquivo e gera um **json** com o hash gerado.

Exemplo do gulp:

```
gulp.task('css-default', function() {
    return gulp.src([
      './static/css/*.css'
    ])
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/assets/css'))
});

gulp.task('css-hash', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./static/assets/css/main.css'])
        .pipe(hash()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/assets/css')) 
        .pipe(hash.manifest('assets.json', { 
          deleteOld: true,
          sourceDir: './static/assets/css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.')); 
});

gulp.task('css', ['css-default'], function(){
    gulp.start('css-hash');
});
```

A primeira `gulp.task` gera o arquivo `main.css` unificando todos os meus CSSs.

A segunda gera o arquivo com hash e um **json** que terá a informação do hash.

A terceira garante que cada uma delas será chamada em sequencia asincrona.

Ai com o json eu pego o nome do arquivo para colocar no `<head>` do site sem precisar fazer replace.